# Angular 2 pipe returning undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a json like this

```
[{
  "id": 9156,
  "slug": "chicken-seekh-wrap",
  "type": "dish",
  "title": "Chicken Seekh Wrap",
  "cuisine_type": [2140]
},
{
  "id": 9150,
  "slug": "green-salad",
  "type": "dish",
  "title": "Green Salad",
  "cuisine_type": [2141]
}]
```

I created a pipe like this to filter by cuisine type in angular2

```
@Pipe({
      name: 'filter',
      pure: false
 })
 export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
     transform(list: Array<any>, searchTerm: any): Array<any> {
        if(!searchTerm) return list;
        else {
           return list.filter(item => item.cuisine_type[0] == searchTerm);
        } 
     }
 }
```

And in the view I have used it like this

```
<li *ngFor="let dish of dishes | filter : 2140">
      <h2>{{dish.title}}</h2>
      <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="dish.id" />
 </li>
```

But it giving me such errors

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at FilterPipe.transform (filter.ts:20)
    at checkAndUpdatePureExpressionInline (core.es5.js:11241)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.es5.js:12096)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12058)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12687)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.es5.js:12628)
    at Object.View_FourthStepPage_1.currVal_0 [as updateDirectives] (FourthStepPage.html:26)
```

I am not understanding what exactly I have done wrong. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: The error is quite obvious right? your `list` is `undefined`. Maybe you should do some validation enforcement before passing the data to the pipe.

Answer (score 2):

If you are fetching your list from a backend, then it might be the case that you haven't fetched the list yet and that your variable is `undefined`. There are 2 things you can do here.

#### Solution 1

Verify in your pipe that the list actually contains a value. I do **not** recommend this approach because you are placing the logic in the wrong place.

**Good software practice**

The pipe should just do the transformation and nothing else. This is what we call the single responsibility principle ([SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)). If you do not do this, you will end up with bloated functions that do sanity checks everywhere and your code will take more effort to test.

A better practice is to sanitize the data before you do the transformation, i.e, setting the initial value of the list to an empty array `[]`.

#### Solution 2

Make sure that either the list is empty initially or that the div with `*ngFor` is not triggered, meaning that you can hide it using an `*ngIf`.

Comment: But I didn't understand this point "because you are placing the logic in the wrong place."

Comment: Hi Maantu, I have added a section and a link to a very important principle in software development called the Single Responsibility Principle. I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: ^^^ solution 2 was a quick easy fix for this when I ran into this issue. appreciate the insights!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, remove the unnecessary ')' from the end of your *ngFor.
Secondly, The error happens because you pass null to your filter.
The filter try to run on null, and because you trying to filter null the error pops.
My suggestion is to add a check if the value witch was passed is valid. try to change your pipe to:

```
@Pipe({
      name: 'filter',
      pure: false
 })
 export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
     transform(list: Array<any>, searchTerm: any): Array<any> {
        if(!list)
          return [];
        if(!searchTerm) return list;
        else {
           return list.filter(item => item.cuisine_type[0] == searchTerm);
        } 
     }
 }
```

In this way, you avoid parsing undefined values..

P.S
If your data is fetched from remote server and dishes holds it's observable, you have to use async pipe as well.

Answer (score 1):

Never seen this syntax ... Try this

```
<li *ngFor="let dish of dishes | filter : 2140">
```

Comment: Oh wait, try this : `<li *ngFor="let dish of dishes | async | filter : 2140">`

Comment: The syntax `<li *ngFor="let dish of ( dishes | filter : 2140 )">` is used to apply the Pipe to the array. `<li *ngFor="let dish of dishes | filter : 2140 ">` is used to apply the Pipe to the each value in the array. He had the proper syntax the first time.

Comment: Don' know what you're talking about : I have **never** used the parenthesis and always "piped" the whole array. I am checking my sort pipe right now, and I use the `sort` property on the value I am receiving. Did this change in newer versions ?

Comment: I could have sworn I read something about applying a pipe on each value rather than the array itself. Nevertheless. The `let value of ( values | pipe: param )` syntax is still valid and honestly cleaner since you are applying a pipe to an iterable for ngFor to use, not to the for statement itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `")"` in this after 2140 `*ngFor="let dish of dishes | filter : 2140)"` Remove that and try, it will work. I have tested it.

Comment: Highly doubt it. You can't have one closing parenthesis hanging out alone, you have to delete it too !

Comment: @trichetriche thats what i am saying that he has an extra ")" which he needs to remove :)

Comment: @trichetriche and i have upvoted your answer because it is the right one.

Comment: Oh osrry my bad, I actually answered when the code was `*ngFor="let dish of (dishes | filter : 2140)"`, my bad !

Comment: Sorry its my mistake..removed it..but still no result